# Передача данных между инпутами

Tags: reactjs, компоненты

Есть два компонента, в каждом по 3 инпута - время, дата, место. Необходимо сделать, что бы по нажатию на кнопку, данные из инпутов менялись между компонентами. Принцип как в гугл картах, когда строишь маршрут из точки А в точку Б и есть возможность поменять их местами.
[image: макет]

Код компонента:

```
const DestinationInfo = () => {
return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.item}>
            <div className={styles.itemTitle}>Locations</div>
            <div className='d-flex flex-row aic jcsb mt-8'>
                <select className={styles.city} name='city' id='city' defaultValue='default'>
                    <option value='default'>Select Your City</option>
                    <option value='moscow'>Moscow</option>
                    <option value='novosibirsk'>Novosibirsk</option>
                </select>
                <img
                    className={styles.arrowDown}
                    width={14}
                    height={14}
                    src='./images/arrow-down.svg'
                    alt='Arrow Down'
                />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.divider}></div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.item}>
            <div className={styles.itemTitle}>Date</div>
            <div className='d-flex flex-row aic jcsb mt-8 pos-r'>
                <input
                    className={styles.date}
                    type='date'
                    name='calendar'
                    min='2023-03-01'
                    max='2024-01-01'
                    placeholder='Date'
                />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.divider}></div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.item}>
            <div className={styles.itemTitle}>Time</div>
            <div className='d-flex flex-row aic jcsb mt-8'>
                <input className={styles.time} type='time' id='time' name='time' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Реакт только изучаю, поэтому о многих вещах могу не догадаться.

Comment: есть смысл делать управляемые компоненты (достаточно одного хука useState на форму). в этом случае изменение объекта автоматически изменит данные на форме. подробнее в [доке](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) по реакту. это честный официальный прием, не хак.